# $v_1,...,v_m,w$ linearly independent $\iff$ $w \notin \text{span}(v_1,...,v_m)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

> Let $v_1,...,v_m$ linearly independant in $V$ and $w\in V$. Show that $v_1,...,v_m,w$ is linearly independent $\iff$ $w \notin \text{span}(v_1,...,v_m)$. It might be a "classic" result in linear algebra, but I would like to know if my proof holds and have a feedback, please.

In the following proof $\mathbf{F}$ will denote a field.

*Proof*

($\implies$) Suppose first that $v_1,...,v_m,w$ is linearly independent. We suppose by absurd that $w \in \text{span}(v_1,...,v_m)$.

Let $\lambda_i \in \mathbf{F}, i =1,2,...,m+1$. By definition we have then that

$\lambda_1v_1+...+\lambda_mv_m+\lambda_{m+1}w=w+\lambda_{m+1}w=w(1+\lambda_{m+1})=0 \iff \lambda_1=...=\lambda_{m+1}=0$.

As $\mathbf{F}$ is integral, we have that $w(1+\lambda_{m+1})=0 \iff w=0$ or $\lambda_{m+1}=-1$. In two cases we have that $\lambda_{m+1}\neq 0$ so contradiction.

($\impliedby$) Suppose now that $w \notin \text{span}(v_1,...,v_m)$. We have then that

$\lambda_1v_1+...+\lambda_mv_m+\lambda_{m+1}w=0 \implies  \lambda_1v_1+...+\lambda_mv_m=-\lambda_{m+1}w$

As $w \notin \text{span}(v_1,...,v_m)$, $\lambda w \notin \text{span}(v_1,...,v_m)$ as well for all $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$. Therefore,

$\lambda_1v_1+...+\lambda_mv_m=-\lambda_{m+1}w=0 \iff \lambda_1=...=\lambda_{m+1}=0$. Thus $v_1,...,v_m,w$ is lenearly independent.

I feel like the second implication doesn't hold, so I would like to have a feedback, please.

Comment: I don't really follow the second direction. What is wrong with simply arguing by contradiction as before? Suppose the set is linearly dependent, then $\exists \lambda_i$ not all equal to 0 such that $\sum_i \lambda_i v_i  + \lambda_{m+1} w = 0$. If $\lambda_{m+1} \neq 0$ then you can solve for $w$ which shows $w$ is in the span. What about the case $\lambda_{m+1} = 0$?

Comment: I distinguished the cases first, then i deleted it because wanted to prove the thing faster then by 2 different cases x) I did the same for $\lambda_{m+1}$ and in the case if $\lambda_{m+1}= 0$ we have simply that $\lambda_1=...=\lambda_m=0$ as $v_1,...,v_m$ is linearly independent. As $\lambda_{m+1}=0$ as well we have that $v_1,..,v_m,w$ is linearly independent. Thank you for the feedback! I'm agree that the second implications is strange I found it false as well